# .groupby().mean() functions not work with me in data analysis

Tags: python, function, analytics, data-analysis

In my Python data-analysis project, I have a dataset of employee attrition, so I have a categorical column name (Attrition) with two values: `0` and `1`. The rest of the dataset includes int, object data types.

It failed to write the `(.mean() )` function when I tried to group the dataset by this categorical column with the `(.groupby)` function, as shown in the below capture:

[Link to issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e98b7.png)

```
# import libraries:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# read the dataset 
df= pd.read_csv('C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/internship/HR-Employee.csv')
df.head()

#EDA Exploration Data Analysis
df.shape # 1470 Raws with 35 columns (factors)
nullValues = df.isnull().sum().sum()#EDA : is to identify the pattterns through different data visualization
nullValues #No null values in this dataset
duplicatedValues= df.duplicated().sum()
duplicatedValues# No duplcated values in this dataset

df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Yes','No'],value = ['1','0'])
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Travel_Rarely',
'Travel_Frequently','Non-Travel'],value = ['2','1','0'])
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Married','Single','Divorced'],value = ['2','1','0'])
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Male','Female'],value = ['1','0'])
#---
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Human Resources','Research & Development','Sales'],value = ['0','1','2'])
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Human Resources','Life Sciences','Marketing','Medical','Technical Degree','Other'],value = ['0','1','2','3','4','5'])
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Healthcare Representative','Human Resources','Laboratory Technician','Manager','Manufacturing Director','Research Director','Research Scientist','Sales Executive','Sales Representative'],value = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])



  
# drop unnecessery columns
DF = df.drop(['EmployeeCount','Over18','StandardHours'])
# Let's see the information of our updated dataset DF
DF.info()
''' This dataset had 1470 samples and 32 attributes,
(24 integer + 8 objects ) No variables have non null/
missing values'''

DF.describe()
left= DF.groupby('Attrition')
left.mean()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as formatted text (not as images).

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? `.mean()` is does not work on non-numeric columns.

Comment: That's not a [mre]. To start, you haven't provided any data and most of the imports are unused. BTW, for specifics: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341), and for more tips: [ask]. Please also take the [tour] if you haven't already, to learn how this site works.

Comment: and its not logic if i convert the categorical columns into numeric right??

Comment: @Xukrao FYI you can just write `[mre]` and it expands into *[mre]*. More comment shorthands [here](/editing-help#comment-formatting). BTW, it's "Stack Overflow", but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: if you want numeric values then you should use `[1, 0]` (without `' '`) instead of `['1', '0']`

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting *"Unsupported operand type(s) for +: int and str"* is good enough to understand the problem. Your field on which you are applying the `mean()` contains data of type int and string.

Try making the data in the column of the same type before applying `mean()` to it.

There are many possible ways to check the different data types in a column, for example, you can check the different data types in a column using:

```
df.<column_name>.apply(type).value_counts()
```

To demonstrate this, I'm taking the [Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/overview) dataset from Kaggle, the dataset looks like:
[image]

The column *"Sex"* has only two unique values, *"male"* and *"female"*:
[image]

Now, I converted the categorical column "Sex" into numeric one:
[image]

Finally, I am applying `groupby()` on the *"Sex"* column and then using the `mean()` as:
[image]

and Voila..... it worked.

By the way, In your code, in the following line, you are converting categorical values to int :

```
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Healthcare Representative','Human Resources','Laboratory Technician','Manager','Manufacturing Director','Research Director','Research Scientist','Sales Executive','Sales Representative'],value = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

But in the rest of the categorical to int conversion, you are mistakenly using the single quotes on the int values as:

```
df = df.replace(to_replace = ['Yes','No'],value = ['1','0'])
```

It will again convert it from one form of str value to another str value. Try to clean it and then check.